# Remove odd characters

Tags: android, mysql, input, non-printing-characters

I've developed an app that syncs its data with a website I also developed. When I input data from on the web and sync the data to my app, sometimes the data comes down with non-printable characters. During my sync process (or better yet, prior to saving the data in my database, perhaps both...), how can I identify and remove the characters?

[image: screen-shot]

Comment: It would probably be _better_ to make sure that your database, web application, and Android application all use the same character set so that these characters are stored properly without being molested.

Comment: I propose the usage of UTF-8 across all services.

Comment: If the app that you wrote doesn't expect these characters, why is the app that you wrote sending them?

Comment: @stark I believe it's happening when data is copied and pasted from a another source. I don't believe the app itself is adding these characters.

Comment: @LukasKnuth That's what I'll end up using. Thanks for the suggestion.